# Android Studio: How do i fix these errors

Tags: android

I got this error when I changed my App Theme to Material Light

> Rendering problem
>    The following classes could not be instantiated:
>     android.support.design.widget.CordinatorLayout
>     android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout"

[image]

And whenever I open Android Studio it displays an error

> Rendering problem
>    The following classes could not be found:
>     android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
>     android.support.design.widget.CordinatorLayout"

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem now with android studio latest version (1.4). I have this problem when i tried to create a simple Blank Activity project and i couldn't then see the design preview

Answer (score 0):

This is an existing issue with the older version of android Studio:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=175595

Update your android studio to 1.3 and above where it has been fixed.

Comment: I have android studio 1.4 (latest one). I have exactly the same problem in the asked question, so is there another solution for that ?